# establecer como valor 0 si el input esta vacio

Tags: javascript, html

estoy haciendo una calculadora en la cual rellenas los campos y hace las operaciones, pero como hago para que, si el input no tiene ningun valor, javascript lo interprete como 0?

```js
var button = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[2];
var input1 = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[1];
var input2 = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0];


button.addEventListener("click", function(){
  console.log(input1.valueAsNumber + input2.valueAsNumber);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/index.css">
    <title>Calculadoras</title>
</head>
<body>
        <form action="">
                <input type="number" step="0.001">
                <input type="number" step="0.001">
                <input type="submit" value="sumar">
        </form>
</body>
<script src="./JavaScript/index.js"></script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que tenés que hacer es reconocer en el evento `submit()` el input y en caso de estar vacío, reemplazarlo por `0`. Podés consultar si es un número mediante [`Number.isNaN()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Number/isNaN).

```js
var input1 = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[1];
var input2 = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0];
var form = document.getElementById('formulario');

form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  if (Number.isNaN(input1.valueAsNumber)) {
    input1.value = 0;
  }
  if (Number.isNaN(input2.valueAsNumber)) {
    input2.value = 0;
  }
  console.log(input1.valueAsNumber + input2.valueAsNumber);
  
  //prevengo que se submitee, sólo para el ejemplo
  e.preventDefault();
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/index.css">
    <title>Calculadoras</title>
</head>
<body>
        <form id="formulario" action="">
                <input type="number" step="0.001">
                <input type="number" step="0.001">
                <input type="submit" value="sumar">
        </form>
</body>
<script src="./JavaScript/index.js"></script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Básicamente necesitas saber si los valores ingresados corresponden a números válidos, y en este caso si se deja el input vacío **NO ES UN NÚMERO**, debes validarlo con la función [isNaN](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_isnan.asp) de `Javascript`

```js
var input1 = document.getElementById("input1");
var input2 = document.getElementById("input2");
var button = document.getElementById("btn");

button.addEventListener("click", function(e){
  if(isNaN(parseInt(input1.value)) || isNaN(parseInt(input2.value))){
    alert('Ingrese ambos números')
  }
  else{
    alert(parseInt(input1.value) + parseInt(input2.value));    
  }
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<form action="">
  <input id="input1" type="number" placeholder="Ingrese un número" step="0.001">
  <input id="input2" type="number" placeholder="Ingrese un número" step="0.001">
  <input id="btn" type="submit" value="sumar">
</form>
<script src="./JavaScript/index.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Si observas coloque a cada elemento del `DOM` un **id**, pero es netamente por costumbre propia; de la forma que obtienes los valores (`getElementsByTagName`) también es válido colega!

Saludos!

Answer (score 1):

Que tal debes usar el operador ternario ?, espero te sirva.

```js
 var button = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[2];


button.addEventListener("click", function(){

var input1 = (document.getElementsByTagName("input")[1].value == "")? 0:document.getElementsByTagName("input")[1].value ;
var input2 = (document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value ==  "")? 0:document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;

 
  console.log(input1*1 + input2*1);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/index.css">
    <title>Calculadoras</title>
</head>
<body>
        <form action="">
                <input type="number" step="0.001">
                <input type="number" step="0.001">
                <input type="submit" value="sumar">
        </form>
</body>
<script src="./JavaScript/index.js"></script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Con uso de jQuery lo puedes hacer muy sencillo... asi:

```
       var input2 =  $("input["+0+"]").val().length;

       if (input2 <= 0) {  
          input2=0;   
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

solamente con agregar un value 0

```js
var button = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[2];
var input1 = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[1];
var input2 = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0];


button.addEventListener("click", function(){
  console.log(input1.valueAsNumber + input2.valueAsNumber);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/index.css">
    <title>Calculadoras</title>
</head>
<body>
        <form action="">
                <input type="number" step="0.001" value=0>
                <input type="number" step="0.001" value=0>
                <input type="submit" value="sumar">
        </form>
</body>
<script src="./JavaScript/index.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: eso no me gusta ya que cada vez que quiera ingresar un valor tendre que borrar el 0, alguna otra manera?

Comment: la que te puse =?

Comment: si establezco en el html el valor como 0, cada vez que haga click en el input para introducir un valor voy a tener que borrar ese 0 y no quiero eso, quiero que se muestre vacio el input pero que si no tiene nada se interprete como 0

Comment: si es asi solo agregale un placeholder y en el placeholder ponle 0 si lo unico que quieres es mostrar un cero

Answer (score -1):

null y la cadena vacía son conceptualmente iguales a cero cuando se tratan como una entidad de tipo Number. La solución más sencilla que se me ocurre es:

Suponer que la variable input es el elemento HTML del input a comprobar (puedes obtenerla con document.querySelector, por ejemplo):

```
var number = Number(input.value)

if (Number.isNaN(number)) {
    // El input en cuestión contenía un valor inválido, como "patata".
} else {
    // El input en cuestión contenía un valor válido. Si input.value es null o "", Number(input.value) es igual a cero. Ahora la variable number contiene el valor deseado.
}
```